# Invalid context 0x0 with FBSDKProfilePictureView

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a bunch of strange warnings in the console while using Facebook SDK 4.1 FBSDKProfilePictureView:

> Error: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Here is my code:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

func getFBProfilePicture(facebookID: String) -> UIView {
    let picView = FBSDKProfilePictureView()
    picView.profileID = facebookID
    picView.pictureMode = FBSDKProfilePictureMode.Square
    return picView as UIView
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, actually you can't initialize a FBProfilePictureView without a frame... Now I know.

Here is the correct code:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit

func getFBProfilePicture(facebookID: String) -> UIView {
    let picView = FBSDKProfilePictureView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    picView.profileID = facebookID
    picView.pictureMode = FBSDKProfilePictureMode.Square
    return picView as UIView
}
```